# Count the number of times the portion of a link beginning with certain string appears in the text of a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to count for each row the number of times the portion of a link beginning with 'https://t.co/' appears in the text of a column named "Tweet_text".

I've done:

```
SELECT COUNT(REGEXP_CONTAINS('https://t.co/', Tweet_text)) As Cnt
FROM `MyTable`
```

But this returns the overall count over the whole table, not the count row by row.

Comment: add unique column representing each row in your query and group by that. example: SELECT myRowId, COUNT(REGEXP_CONTAINS('https://t.co/', Tweet_text)) As Cnt
FROM `MyTable`  group by myRowId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Tweet_text, 'https://t.co/'))
FROM MyTable
```

The function [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) only returns the state whether your regular expression was found:

> Returns `TRUE` if `value` is a partial match for the regular expression, `regexp`.

If you want to get the count of found substring in your column you have to use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) with [`ARRAY_LENGTH`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length).

You get the count of each row (not a sum) because you don't use a aggregate function (like `COUNT`) anymore.